# ColdFusion CFForm Select Box Item Selected

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfform

I have a drop down that filters a multi-select box that then the user selects items from.

How can I make this work when Editing.

I need to change the selected item and make the multi-select populate based on the selected item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `<cfselect bind="" ...>`

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7afe.html

Comment: I know about that.  I want the previous selected options to show up and still be bound to the cfc.

Comment: you can write Javascript to pre-select the options for your "edit" view.